# Can't access my Flask App on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS from the Internet

Tags: raspberrypi, nginx, port-forwarding, flask

I recently bought a `Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB)` and installed `Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS` on it.

My goal is to turn it into a server to host all my `Python` scripts (`Flask Websites`/`Telegram Bots`/etc) on it. [Pretty much like a local `Heroku` server]

Now, I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/goToXTC96Co) blindly, and was successfully able to set up my `Flask` app. However, the problem is unlike the video where the website **could be accessed** from the `internet`, mine can **only be accessed** from my `Local Network` through the server's `IP`. When I shared this `IP` to my friends they are not able to view my website.

Now, I did some research and found out about `port forwarding`. But that does not seem to work either.

Was hoping to find some answers here.

Here's my `nginx` configuration file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.29.49;

        location /static {
                alias /home/tech_savvy_guy/My-Website/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvGXF.png) of the `port forwarding` that I enabled on my router.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access it from your LAN, then it works. Period. Don't muck with it.

Everything after that is non-Ubuntu-related networking.

Your router has two addresses:

- One for the LAN (like 192.168.1.1)
- Another public address for the wider internet (like 38.25.67.186).

Your nearby friends on the LAN must use the LAN address.

Your distant friends out on the internet must use the public address.

Ask Google "What is my IP address?" and the return you get will be your router's public address...since Google does not have a server on your LAN.

All the devices on your LAN share that single public IP address. To the internet, your whole LAN resembles a single busy device (your router). That's why you need to use Port Forwarding on your router: So the router knows which LAN device Port 80 requests should be *forwarded* to.

Comment: Sorry, if the question was not proper. I am completely clueless in this matter.

May you kindly tell me what you mean by "the router's public IP address"?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the edit! I did find my `IPv4` address: `49.37.47.217`

Now, I tried accessing the website from the internet via: `http://49.37.47.217:80` but it still does not work.

Comment: "*It still does not work*" is too vague to offer useful advice. SOMETHING happened. Since we were not looking over your shoulder, we don't know what feedback you received. If it was an error message or some web page that you did not expect to see, the complete details would be very useful troubleshooting information.

Comment: @user535733 When I visit this URL: `http://49.37.47.217:80` I am not able to see my website. Instead the browser shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsOxo.png).

I also believe that since this is my public IP address even you can view the website?

Comment: You will need to learn about the firewalls protecting your laptop.  As a start, you should look into the **iptables** command.  You will need to adjust firewall rules to allow some incoming traffic.

Comment: @mondotofu As a matter of fact, I did install `ufw` on my system.

To allow incoming traffic I ran the command: `sudo ufw default allow incoming` followed by `sudo ufw enable`.

To restart the `ngnix` server, I then ran: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

But, still I can't view my website through the internet. It still says: `49.37.42.217 took too long to respond`

Comment: are your friends trying port 80 or 8000 ?

Comment: @mondotofu They're using port 80 like this: http://49.37.47.217:80

Comment: Traceroute and Ping output on that IP address suggests that your ISP might be blocking. Try port-forwarding a different port on the router. For example forward internet port 8080 to your server port 80. Then try 49.37.47.217:8080

Comment: @user535733 Does that mean I have to change the `nginx` configuration file too?

Comment: If you can access the Ubuntu Server from your LAN, then it works. Period. Don't muck with it.